# Curve fitting for large datasets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, curve-fitting, scatter-plot

I have a very large set of data, ( around 100k points) and I want to fit a curve to this plot.

I tried the filters suggested by answers to another question, but that lead to overfitting.
I am using numpy and matplotlib as of now.

[This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwijx7j325HmAhWv_XMBHSV_ADYQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffigure%2FI-B-I-color-magnitude-diagram-for-the-entire-CFHT-dataset_fig3_1749812&psig=AOvVaw1ZWRSPTHnDv3y4Qg_uhrAV&ust=1575195836096112) is the type of scatter plot I am trying to fit.

Edit 1:

Please ignore the data points to the side of the central main set of data points(Thus only a single curve can fit this)

[Here](https://archive.stsci.edu/hlsps/hugs/ngc2808/hlsp_hugs_hst_wfc3-uvis-acs-wfc_ngc2808_multi_v1_catalog-meth1.txt) is the dataset, download the file as a text file to separate the columns, consider the columns 3 and 9 ( 1-based indexing), the y-axis has column 3 while the x-axis plots the difference of column 3 and column 9.

Edit 2: Ignore the negative values

Edit 3: As there appears to be a lot of noise, consider the column 33 which accounts for probability and consider stars only which have >90% probability

Comment: By visual appearance, a single function will not fit this data because there appears to be multiple data groups on the same plot. To me it appears as if there should me multiple models individually fitted to the different data groups. If you do this, the number of data points in each model is reduced.

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data set?

Comment: @JamesPhillips Yes I'll edit the question

Comment: Some of the values in these columns are negative. Should I exclude them?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I'm so sorry I forgot to tell that, yes exclude them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is are comparison scatterplots using the data in your link, along with the python code I used to read, parse, and plot the data. Note that my plot also has an inverted y axis for direct comparison. This shows me that the data in the posted link, parsed per your directions, cannot be fit as it is per your question. My hope is that you can find some error in my work, and a model can in fact be made.

[image: comparison_plots]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataFileName = 'temp.dat'

dataCount = 0
xlist = []
ylist = []
with open(dataFileName) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line[0] == '#': # comments
            continue

        spl = line.split()
        col3 = float(spl[2])
        col9 = float(spl[8])

        if col3 < 0.0 or col9 < 0.0:
            continue

        x = abs(col3 - col9)
        y = col3

        xlist.append(x)
        ylist.append(y)

f = plt.figure()
axes = f.add_subplot(111)
axes.invert_yaxis()
axes.scatter(xlist, ylist,color='black', marker='o', lw=0, s=1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As there appears to be a lot of noise, consider the column 33 which accounts for probability and consider stars only which have >90% probability

Comment: Interesting change. I see some similar features in the two scatterplots, most curious. In terms of making a regression model, however, I must resort to using somewhat arcane technical jargon and note that - in my personal opinion - fitting all of that data simultaneously  to a single y = f(x) type of mathematical model will not yield diddely-squat.